# How to unset billing fields in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to unset billing fields like so:

```php
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']); 
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']); 
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']); 
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']); 
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']); 
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']); 
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
```

My question is how can I set this functions to run if specific id is in cart.
I tried the following but it didn't work:

```php
if ( 5114 === $product->get_id() ) 
{ 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your question to describe what WooCommerce hook you are using.

Comment: If you liked my response can you make it the accepted answer?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I assume $fields is something you've gotten from the WooCommerce hook like described here:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

So within your hook, you can access the cart like so:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $cart = $woocommerce->cart;

  /* Then iterate over the product in the cart: */

  foreach ($cart_contents as $key => $product_a) {
    $product = $product_a['data'];
    if (/* your condition */) {
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']); 
      /* check your product, and then do something */
    }
  }

  /* Then don't forget at the end to call */

  return $fields;
 }
```